# Make JOIN query match even if row being joined does not exist

Tags: c#, linq, join

Lets say I have the Tables, `Invoices`, and `Customers`  . All invoices are supposed to have a customer but not all do have.

**I want to select all Invoices and join it to the customer** the problem is that if the invoice does not have a customer then that invoice will not show up in the results.

What I have now is:

```
var query = from inv in Db.Invoices                        
            join cust in Db.Customers on inv.IdCustomer equals cust.Id
            select new { Invoice=inv, Customer=cust };
```

That query works great if the invoice has a customer. **How can I select a null Customer and still have the query return me all invoices in case the customer is not found?** I want the query to return me all invoices and if customer is there join it otherwise return me a null Customer.

I know I can do 2 nested for loops but I don't think that will be that efficient and when dealing with more joins it will be even worse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do a left join

```
var query = from inv in Db.Invoices                        
            from cust in Db.Customers.Where(x => inv.IdCustomer == x.Id).DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new { Invoice = inv, Customer = cust };
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Magnus said, you need left join. You can do it with syntax based query using `join * in * on * equals * into` pattern:

```
var query = from inv in Db.Invoices                        
            join c in Db.Customers on inv.IdCustomer equals c.Id into customers
            from cust in customers.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new { Invoice = inv, Customer = cust };
```

It's described on MSDN:

> A left outer join is a join in which each element of the first collection is returned, regardless of whether it has any correlated elements in the second collection. You can use LINQ to perform a left outer join by calling the DefaultIfEmpty method on the results of a group join.
>
> *from [How to: Perform Left Outer Joins (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx)*